# R applying t.test comparing multiple group and exprot result as a table

Tags: r

I have a data look like:

```
> Group Time Result
>     A 1   933
>     A 2   992
>     A 3   1007
>     A 4   1428
>     A 5   1068
>     A 6   721
>     A 1   1175
>     A 2   900
>     A 3   875
>     A 4   1775
>     A 5   986
>     A 6   963
>     A 1   1394
>     A 2   958
>     A 3   919
>     A 4   1103
>     A 5   940
>     A 6   919
>     C 2   1127
>     C 3   990
>     C 4   1033
>     C 5   1073
>     C 6   817
>       ....
```

and I have total 50 groups, and each grous have 6 time point, so I want to the P value result as a table, using t.test:

```
>     Time：1                    
>       A   B   C   D   E
>     A /   N   N   N   N
>     B N   /   N   N   N
>     C N   N   /   N   N
>     D N   N   N   /   N
>     E N   N   N   N   /
>                                                                   
>     Time：2                    
>       A   B   C   D   E
>     A /   N   N   N   N
>     B N   /   N   N   N
>     C N   N   /   N   N
>     D N   N   N   /   N
>     E N   N   N   N   /
```

Is this possible?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: does `?pairwise.t.test` get you anywhere?

Comment: What is your research question (hypothesis) explicitly?

Comment: @Andre Elrico, yes I could do pairwise.t.test, while the result id too long,  so I want the result look like a table.

Comment: @Patrik_P  For this case, my research is the cell size change along with time, treated cells with different reagent, observed each 1 hour and total for 6 hours.

Comment: what is "the result id" ? I thought its the continious variable to test.

Comment: sorry,typing mistakes. what I want to say is "result", without "id". And the variable should be test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  split(.$Time) %>% 
  map(~pairwise.t.test(.$Result, .$Group, p.adjust.method = "none"))
```

Comment: Thank you! It's helpful, and my result are table now.